# Function definition in Model or Controller

Tags: cakephp

I am new in cakephp, using version 2.3. I am confused in a situation where, I have to get data from database. Where should I define my function (Controller / Model)?

For Example:
There are 3 tables: Users, Destination, and User_destinations. First two are master table and last one is relationship table. Now I have to find the list of destination, visited by users. So, where Should I write function

get_destination_List_for_user($id)

Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: destinations would be great as you are finding list of destinations. But you can define it in controller ,there is no restriction by cakephp.

Comment: Thanks, Ned. It works in both cases, but what would be ideal case suggested by cakephp?

Comment: its will be more simple with relationship defined by cakephp i.e. hasOne,belongsto etc see the documentation.

Comment: @nedstark Well, there is no restriction in any framework but you encourage bad practice. Code like this should always go into the model layer to keep it DRY, easier unit testing, better re-usability.

Comment: Thanks, Burzum. I got my answer.

Comment: @burzum agree with you. It would be ideal to keep it in model. Not in cakephp but for all frameworks too.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP uses the **Active Record** -pattern which at first means that the model provides functions to interact with the database via CRUD-opreations (create, read, update and delete) and at second it implements the **business logic**.

In addition, it is suggestive to implement the function in any related model.

Conclusion: I recommend to implement your function in the model `Destination` or `User` and invoke it in your contoller.